# How to build MongoDB pipeline and append stages to the pipeline using .Net Core MongoDB Driver

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, aggregation-framework, pipeline

this is my first time creating a system using Net Core and MongoDB, I manage to build fully working CRUD with sort and pagination by sending all input parameter in controller to the service layer to query from DATABASE.

this is my input parameter for Get Action...

```
 **public IActionResult Get(string userID, string sellerID, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo, string search, string sortValue, string filter, int offset = 0, int limit = 10)**
```

I succeeded at creating FilterdefinitionBuilder and SortDefinitionBuilder

```
**//MongoDB Definition Builder
#region MongoDB Definition builder
FilterDefinitionBuilder<OrderModel> filterBuilder = Builders<OrderModel>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<OrderModel> filterDefinition = filterBuilder.Empty;
             
SortDefinitionBuilder<OrderModel> sortBuilder = Builders<OrderModel>.Sort;
SortDefinition<OrderModel> sortDefinition = sortBuilder.Ascending(x => x.ID);
#endregion**
```

#example 1

```
**if (sortValue.ToUpper() == "DESC")
{
     sortDefinition = sortDefinition.Descending(x => x.ID);
}**
```

#Example 2

**//Validate date range

```
#region dateFrom and dateTo
if (dateFrom.HasValue && dateTo.HasValue)
{
    if (dateFrom.Value < dateTo.Value.AddDays(1))
    {
    filterDefinition = filterDefinition & filterBuilder.Gte(x => x.CreatedDate, dateFrom.Value) & 
    filterBuilder.Lt(y => y.CreatedDate, dateTo.Value.AddDays(1));
    }
}
#endregion**
```

What I wish to accomplish is creating a empty pipeline using builder similarly to what I did with sortDefinition and filterDefinition, and then when certain conditions are met, create a pipeline stage and add into the pipeline.

I have been surfing online for the answer to no avail but to my little understanding, I believe that I can remove both sortDefinition and filterDefinition and just use stages available in pipeline to accomplish CRUD,sort and pagination by using stages e.g. "Match","sort","skip","limit". But till now I still don't know the right syntax

[Pipeline choices suggested by Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4y38.png)

kindly asking if anyone knows how to accomplish this.

Regard,
Hazmin

Comment: Hi Hazim. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at Atlas Search? It will sort by relevance on its own, and the search results will be parsed much faster. You can sort on numeric fields with the `near` operator in a `$search` stage.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing @Nice-Guy, I will look into it, but I would like to learn how to build a pipeline, I have look everywhere for the pass few days, but haven't found the right C# codes to do this similarly to how I build a sortDefinition and filterDefinition, If you or anyone else have the knowledge on building a pipeline in c#, I sincerely appreciate if you could show me an example of how to build a pipeline in the controller that I later can add stages to it depending on input validation; and then send just one pipelineDefinition to service layer. Thanks

Comment: I have pasted an example of how to generate a pipeline with MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm putting my solution here for future reference and also hope it helps anyone who is trying to create a project using C# and mongoDB. My intentions is to create a code that has the potential to be used as a static class; something that is reusable for every filtered Get Method. this is what I have done so far...

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetFiltered()
{
    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter;
    var sort = Builders<User>.Sort;
    ProjectionDefinition<User,User> projection = Builders<User>.Projection.Include(x=>x.FirstName);

    PipelineDefinition<User, User> pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<User>();
    pipeline = pipeline.Match(filter.Eq(x => x.Password, null));
    pipeline = pipeline.Match(filter.Eq(x => x.FirstName, "Hazmin"));
    pipeline = pipeline.Skip(0);
    pipeline = pipeline.Limit(3);
    pipeline = pipeline.Sort(sort.Ascending(x => x.LastName));
    pipeline = pipeline.Project(projection);

var users = _userService.GetAll(pipeline);
return Ok(users);
}
```

Hope It will somewhat helps... will update soon for more upgrades.

Thanks for reading...

Regards,
Hazmin

Comment: Do you know how to add another stage to count the total number of items in the matched results (to show no. of pages), so that you don't have to run 2 queries?